# R - zoo plots customization

Tags: r, plot, time-series, zoo

I have data in a zoo object which has multiple columns. 
Now I want to plot (four of those columns) two columns in same and two in graph below the previous graph.

To be more precise, I have been able to plot the four of them one below the other. 
But I want first two in the same plot and last two in the next plot

[image]

Comment: Use the `screens=` argument of `plot.zoo`.  In the examples section at the bottom of `?plot.zoo` the last example in the multivariate plotting section puts two of the three plots in one panel.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but I might also suggest you take a look at the (new) plot.xts method in my xtsExtra package, available off R-Forge. It's a major revamp of plot.xts and is part of some GSOC work. Given your axis labels, I'd guess you're in HFT and as Brian Peterson has said on R-SIG-Finance before: "if you're doing finance and you're not using xts, you're doing it wrong." Since xts inherits from zoo, the syntax is rather similar, something like plot(dat, screens = c(1,1,2,2), layout = matrix(1:2, ncol = 1)) but you get nice formatting (as well as cool customizability).

Comment: Following on myself since I was about to hit the character limit: Note that it's all highly experimental code and likely to change. I know most FOSS comes with NO WARRANTY, [to quote R's ominous startup banner] but this is double-super NO WARRANTY.

Comment: Thanks a lot. xts and zoo seem like the way to go. Amazing visualizations.

Answer (score 1):

It should work by adding `nc=2` in your plot command (ie number of columns = 2).